# Converting decimal to int in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, decimal

I am trying to convert a column from a Table from decimal to int or bigint.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spr_ODW_GetStocksForGlobalPart]
    @globalPartId bigint
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT     
        dbo.tbl_ODW_SvPartSapLocation.stockBlocked, 
        dbo.tbl_ODW_SvPartSapLocation.stockUnrestricted, 
        dbo.tbl_ODW_SvPartSapLocation.stockValuated, 
        dbo.tbl_ODW_SvPartSapLocation.stockValuatedCurrency, 
        tbl_ODW_SapLocation.name as sapLocationName
    FROM         
        dbo.tbl_ODW_GlobalPart 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.tbl_ODW_SvPartSapLocation ON dbo.tbl_ODW_GlobalPart.id = dbo.tbl_ODW_SvPartSapLocation.globalPartId
    INNER JOIN
        tbl_ODW_SapLocation ON  dbo.tbl_ODW_SvPartSapLocation.sapLocationId = tbl_ODW_SapLocation.id
    WHERE     
        (dbo.tbl_ODW_GlobalPart.id = @globalPartId)

UPDATE [dbo].[spr_ODW_GetStocksForGlobalPart]
ALTER COLUMN dbo.tbl_ODW_SvPartSapLocation.stockValuated int/bigint
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Tag dbms used. (That code is far from ANSI SQL...)

Comment: It's written in T-SQL

Comment: Have you not tried [`CAST` or `CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: As far as I know a conversion to decimal to int is in implicit and it's made automatically and I don't need CAST or CONVERT,but I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ALTER TABLE` to modify the table's structure:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_ODW_SvPartSapLocation]
ALTER COLUMN stockValuated INT
```

`UPDATE` is used to update *data rows* in the table - not the table structure.

If you just want to change the data type in your stored procedure when selecting from the table, use `CAST`:

```
SELECT     
    dbo.tbl_ODW_SvPartSapLocation.stockBlocked, 
    dbo.tbl_ODW_SvPartSapLocation.stockUnrestricted, 
    CAST(dbo.tbl_ODW_SvPartSapLocation.stockValuated AS INT), 
    .......
```

Comment: I want to understand,I can't update the column in the stored procedure?

Comment: Maybe you had asked the wrong question. To change the column  type you must follow @marc_s answer. But if all you want is to fetch that values in a different type you can use `CAST` or `CONVERT`